# A sequence of random variables converge to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to solve this probability problem.

> Let $(\epsilon_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative integer iid random variables. We consider $X_n$ the number of distinct values of the set of $\{\epsilon_1,\ldots, \epsilon_n\}$. Prove that $\frac{X_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s.

If the variable $\epsilon$ is bounded the solution is trivial. I also observe that $X_{n+1}$ can take only the two values $X_n$ or $X_n+1$ so I tried to compute the probability of $\{X_n +1 = X_{n+1}\}$ but without any assumption on the distribution of $\epsilon$ it seems to be hard. Can any one help me with an idea ?

Comment: Can you clarify your notation; if $\epsilon_n$ are the random variables, what do you define $X_n$ as? You say this is the cardinality of the set $\{\epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n\}$. The cardinality of this is $n$, if seen as a set of random variables. Do you mean the number of distinct values taken by the $\epsilon_n$? i.e. if $n=3, \epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2 = 1, \, \epsilon_3 = 2$ then $X_n = 2$?

Comment: I meant the number of distinct values